# how to "trace" a program such as shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I understand that `dash` is a "model" shell - it was written recently and well and it only implements what is required of POSIX shell.  I looked at the dash source code to understand how "tracing" of a program such as shell, is done.

"Tracing" of dash is performed by compiling it with `DEBUG` defined and invoking with `-o debug`.  When you do that, a file `trace` is opened up with `fopen` to which information is dumped about what `dash` is doing when it runs.

Except the whole mechanism, appears to me, does not work, even in this "perfectly written" shell.  If I have this in a shell script:

```
exec 3>&1
```

immediately all information after that, is very likely no longer dumped to file `trace` but winds up on `stdout`.  That is because `fopen` calls `open` and that likely returns file descriptor 3.

This is not a contrived example.  There are real-world commonly used scripts that have lines like

`exec`number`>&1`

(I saw that in 2 autotools `configure` scripts: for IP Infusion and Kerberos software).

So how can a shell be debugged/traced, when it has to run scripts like these?

(I am not looking for tools outside shell - I want to know what is the correct way to trace, inside a program such as shell.  Or is it not possible in general?)

Comment: "strace -f" may or may not be helpful

Comment: @barrycarter yes, thank you, good point, but...  I want to do it inside the shell - clarified the question.  Basically, I want to know, if God wrote a shell, how would they implement tracing.  Or is it not possible in general due to the above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a socket ([syslogd](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_syslogd.htm) does this for example). But then how would you protect against commands like

```
LD_PRELOAD=my_bogus_socket_funcs.so somecommand
```

Or you could use [`dup2`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) to change the file descriptor to a higher number. But that is no guarantee, maybe only protection against script mistakes (such as using 3 instead of 2 in redirects).

If the script wants to change tracing behaviour on purpose, I believe there is not much a shell could (or should) do.

Comment: it is not that "script wants to change tracing on purpose", these scripts do not.  I am not looking to run rogue scripts, just poorly written ones.  The script uses 3 for some other purpose, it has that hardcoded, and it does not know, that somebody may already have that open.

Comment: yes I think `dup2` to a "magic number file descriptor" is probably my best bet...  thank you

Comment: In that particular case either approach would have worked. My point is that unless you *know* the mistakes that are in the script, there is really no way of guaranteeing that they would run. Scripts may have valid reasons to do things like overriding socket functions (I have used it myself).